# Magento 2 - Check if product have custom option required

Tags: magento2, product, php, magento2.3, custom-options

how I can check in list.phtml if a product have custom options and if Required field is selected?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$hasRequired = false;
$options = $_product->getOptions();
if (is_array($options)) {
    foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $option) {
        if ($option->getIsRequire()) {
            $hasRequired = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

now check the value of `$hasRequired`;

(`$_product` - is the product instance for which you are checking)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: can you please check that code I put in the list.phtml and I have this error on frontend:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: maybe check what `($_product->getOptions()` returns. maybe it does not return an array. I've updated the answer

Comment: I just put the code in the list.phtml is magento 2.3.4 version